# UITableview cell shadow not appearing in ios 13

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OPeu.jpg)i am using the following code to make shadow for uitableview cell. Its working fine on all ios versions except ios 13.

```
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 81.0/255.0, green: 245.0/255.0, blue: 245.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    cell.brlogo.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    cell.brlogo.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

    cell.brlogo.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

How can i make shadow to uitableview cell on ios 13?
Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: is there spacing in between Cells ? Can you post the output you got ?

Comment: i added out image link in post check that. in ios 13 blue lines under cell not appearing

Comment: `layer.masksToBounds = false` and `cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8`

Comment: try it out .. it will help

Comment: I tried. its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add view in table cell and give constraints some smaller to table cell constraints and give shadow to that view and add other components in that view